# Postgres: Are There Downsides to Using a JSON Column vs. an integer[] Column?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

---

**TLDR:** If I want to save arrays of integers in a Postgres table, are there any pros or cons to using an array column (`integer[]`) vs. using a JSON column (eg. does one perform better than the other)?

**Backstory:**

I'm using a PostgreSQL database, and Node/Knex to manage it.  Knex doesn't have any way of directly defining a PostgreSQL `integer[]` column type, so someone filed a Knex bug asking for it ... but one of the Knex devs closed the ticket, essentially saying that there was no need to support PostgreSQL array column types when anyone can instead use the JSON column type.

My question is, what downsides (if any) are there to using a JSON column type to hold a simple array of integers?  Are there any benefits, such as improved performance, to using a true array column, or am I equally well off by just storing my arrays inside a JSON column?

**EDIT:** Just to be clear, all I'm looking for in an answer is either of the following:

A) an explanation of how JSON columns and integer[] columns in PostgreSQL work, including either how one is better than the other or how the two are (at least roughly) equal.

B) no explanation, but at least a reference to some benchmarks that show that one column type or the other performs better (or that the two are equal)

Comment: `JSON(B)` is much more complex type then simple array so it requires more manipulations (internally at least) to manage its values; arrays could be indexed in simple way while `JSON` arrays could not (as I know); there are a lot of functions/operators to handle arrays in PostgreSQL while for `JSON(B)` arrays only one way is to convert it to the set of values and handle them one by one...

Comment: Yeah, I'm mainly curious about JSON not JSON(B).  As for the `integer[]` columns being indexed and the JSON not, that was my initial thought too, but the Knex people tend to be very knowledgeable about databases, so I figured their suggestion to use JSON might be based on a superior understanding of the matter (as I'm far from a Postgres expert).

Comment: In few words: if you need an array of integers then use array of integers. You always can to convert it to `JSON` array simply using `to_json()` or `to_jsonb()` function. [Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) and [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html).

Comment: `JSON(B)` columns could be indexed but for limited set of conditions (for example, like `key=value` or `field contains some key`) [Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING)

Comment: So then do you have any idea why the Knex developers might have suggested using JSON columns instead of `integer[]` columns?  Is there any chance that JSON columns with simple values (like one array) might be indexed almost as well by Postgres for instance?  Do you know of anyone who has run benchmarks, or could you explain why they are unnecessary because of the ____ aspect of how the two work?  Ideally I'm looking for more than "few words", I'm looking for an answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I can to give the opinion from PostgreSQL side. And I have no any ideas why Knex developers thinks that using JSON columns could be more efficient then natural type(s) (except that parsing of JSON-containing strings is simpler for them)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An `int[]` is a lot more efficient in terms of storage it requires. Consider the following query which returns the size of an array with 500 elements

```
select pg_column_size(array_agg(i)) as array_size, 
       pg_column_size(jsonb_agg(i)) as jsonb_size,
       pg_column_size(json_agg(i)) as json_size
from  generate_series(1,500) i;
```

returns:

```
array_size | jsonb_size | json_size
-----------+------------+----------
      2024 |       6008 |      2396
```

<sup>(I am quite surprised that the JSON value is so much smaller than the JSONB, but that's a different topic)</sup>

---

If you always use the array as a **single** value it does not really matter in terms of query performance But if you *do* need to look into the array and search for specific value(s), that will be a lot more efficient with a native array.

There are a lot more functions and operators available for [native arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) than there are for JSON arrays. You can easily search for a single value in a JSON array, but searching for multiple values requires workarounds.

The following query demonstrates that:

```
with array_test (id, int_array, json_array) as (
  values
    (1, array[1,2,3], '[1,2,3]'::jsonb)
)
select id, 
       int_array @> array[1] as array_single,
       json_array @> '1' json_single,
       int_array @> array[1,2] as array_all,
       json_array ?& array['1','2'] as json_all,
       int_array && array[1,2] as array_any,
       json_array ?| array['1','2'] as json_any
from array_test;
```

You can easily query an array if it contains one specific value. This also works for JSON arrays. Those are the expressions `array_single` and `json_single`. With a native array you could also use `1 = any(int_array)` instead.

But check if an array contains all values from a list, or any value from a list does not work with JSON arrays.

The above test query returns:

```
id | array_single | json_single | array_all | json_all | array_any | json_any
---+--------------+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------+---------
 1 | true         | true        | true      | false    | true      | false
```

Comment: Perfect: your response was informative, answered  the question, and let me understand Postgres a little bit better.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually the part saying `there is not a single function or operator that supports searching inside a JSON array` is not true (I count jsonb under general term JSON too).  @>, ?, ?| etc. all supports querying from jsonb arrays and one can also create indexes to make those operations efficient. `Creating Indexes` for jsonb arrays / columns `is not nearly impossible`, but actually quite easy (I wrote a blog post about it couple of years ago https://www.vincit.fi/en/blog/objection-js-postgresql-power-json-queries/ in the end is info about creating indexes).

Comment: @MikaelLepist: Hmm, I was pretty sure @> did not work with arrays. Thanks for the feedback. But e.g. `?|` or `?&` to check for multiple values does not seem to work: http://rextester.com/QEVK30483

Comment: You are right, I remembered totally wrong what `?` operators were for in jsonb. They indeed work for querying if key(s) exist in josnb object (always false for jsonb arrays).